# Angular service worker update view when cache is updated after API response

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I am using Angular service worker to cache my API response.

I am Using following configuration to cache the API:-

```
"dataGroups":[
    {
        "name":"services",
        "urls":[
                   "apiUrl"
               ],
        "cacheConfig": {
                           "maxSize": 1,
                           "maxAge": "1d",
                           "timeout": "0s",
                           "strategy": "freshness"
                       }
        }
]
```

For the first time it is caching the response on service call and on second time its showing data from the cache and making the API call in parallel. After API response it is updating the cache only.
But I want to update my view also when the cache is updated.
For now I've to reload my page to see the updated data, Is there any way to update data on view when API calls returns a response without reloading the page (Cache then network strategy with angular service worker).

Comment: 1. look at ngrx

Comment: 2. if in our component u use @Input() and changeDetection: OnPush u must reInit object/array (Array.from(...) / Object.assign({}, OUR_OBJECT) / new YOUR_CLASS_NAME(DATA)) data what u give to your component

Comment: 3. u can emit event from service when new data was loaded and subscribe to that event from component and than refresh component data

Comment: Please have a look into this:  https://www.prestonlamb.com/blog/rxjs-cache-and-refresh-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

Make cache data in your service an object of type `BehaviorSubject`. Subscribe to it in your component where the view resides. Update your view inside subscription callback.
For example,

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// apiService.service.ts
cacheData = new BehaviorSubject<your_cache_object>(/*initial_value*/)

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

cache() {
    return cacheData.asObservable();
}

api_request() {
    // I expect that yor GET request returns exactly object of type your_cache_object
    // otherwise, please parse your response as your_cache_object
    return this.http.get<your_cache_object>("address").
         pipe(
             tap(response => {
                 this.cacheData.next(data); // cacheData now holds data as the last emitted object
             }));
}

// app.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
    // update view after API call returned a response
    this.apiService.cache.subscribe(data => {
        // update your properties used in the view
    });

    this.apiService.api_request().subscribe();
}
```

Stackblitz app.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6iujsm

Comment: How can I get cache data stored by the service worker?

Comment: can you please create stackblitz or plunker with this example, It'll be really helpful.